# Problem with button click event in jquery

Tags: jquery, button, html, click

I am using jQuery on button click to show div but don't know why its not working...

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="addmoresg" value="Add More" name="button">
<div id="addsg" style="display:none">
    <!-- more HTML here -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addmoresg').click(function() {
        $('.addsg').show("slow");
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XGVp3/

I am not getting any result on button click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2 problems:

1. You did not select jQuery as library in your demo.
2. You use [`class` selectors *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (`.addmoresg`) instead of [`id` selectors *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`#addmoresg`). Your elements only have `id`s, not `class`es:

   ```
   <input type="button" id="addmoresg" value="Add More" name="button">
   ```

   `$('.addmoresg)` would select elements with `class="addmoresg"`, e.g.

   ```
   <input type="button" class="addmoresg" value="Add More" name="button">
   ```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XGVp3/1/)

jQuery has a great [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) and a [list of all possible selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), with examples.

Comment: I knew about that both the we should have selector. and for id we use # and for class we use dot. but same was not working in morning... Still also I have just remove comments in my previous code and its working..

Answer (score 0):

just change your code as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addmoresg').click(function() {
        $('#addsg').show("slow");
    });
});
```

Basically, you were targeting the class `adddsg` (done by a `.class`). Since the div has and ID of `adddsg`, you need to target using `#ID`

Hope that helps.